# NTFS Limitations -- max fragments per file

Tags: ntfs

I read in [this guide](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mikelag/2011/02/09/how-fragmentation-on-incorrectly-formatted-ntfs-volumes-affects-exchange/) that there is a

> "1.5 million approximate maximum amount of fragments that you can
>   have for any given file"

I have been searching but I've been unable to turn up any documentation that supports this claim. Is it true?

Comment: If I were to hazard to guess, it's not publically documented, the article is clearly written from the perspective of somebody with NTFS development time.

Comment: "We cannot give an exact file size limit for a compressed or a highly fragmented file. An estimate would depend on using certain average sizes to describe the structures. These, in turn, determine how many structures fit in other structures. If the level of fragmentation is high, the limit is reached earlier." From We cannot give an exact file size limit for a compressed or a highly fragmented file. An estimate would depend on using certain average sizes to describe the structures."

Comment: ... "These, in turn, determine how many structures fit in other structures. If the level of fragmentation is high, the limit is reached earlier." Source [A heavily fragmented file in an NTFS volume may not grow beyond a certain size](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/967351/a-heavily-fragmented-file-in-an-ntfs-volume-may-not-grow-beyond-a-cert)

Comment: @DavidPostill that looks to be referencing the actual file size, not the number of fragments per file

Comment: @ryansin "When a file is very fragmented, NTFS uses more space to save the description of the allocations that is associated with the fragments. The allocation information is stored in one or more file records. When the allocation information is stored in multiple file records, another structure, known as the ATTRIBUTE_LIST, stores information about those file records. The number of ATTRIBUTE_LIST_ENTRY structures that the file can have is limited."

Comment: From your link "NTFS does have it’s limitations with the overall size of this attribute list per file and can have roughly around 1.5 million fragments.". It's the **attribute list** that has the limit. That agrees with my link.@ryansin

Comment: This is all Microsoft has to say about it...https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/967351/a-heavily-fragmented-file-in-an-ntfs-volume-may-not-grow-beyond-a-cert